# SuperGridControl in DotNetBar has something weird?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagrid, dotnetbar

I used GridControl in DevExpress and at first it puzzled me a little to find out how to use it, but now SuperGridControl in DotNetBar is another one which is even harder to use. This has a GridPanel (returned from PrimaryGrid property)which is like DataGridView. It has a DataSource property and I've tried assigning it with some data source, the rows and columns are populated OK, but next I've tried accessing one of its columns or rows, it threw an exception of IndexOutOfRangeException. The Columns and Rows properties have the Count being equal to 0, what? My sample data source after being filled into the PrimaryGrid has 2 columns and 3 rows but the PrimaryGrid.Columns and PrimaryGrid.Rows are empty???

It's so weird, I think Columns and Rows contain only what we add using code or designer, not for DataSource binding?

Any idea on this problem? Weird much more than GridControl in DevExpress. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you try    **superGridControl1.Refresh();**  before try to access the cell